# Extract path like strings from string

Tags: string, python-2.7, substring, extract

In Python is there are easy way to extract strings that look like paths from larger strings?

For example, if:

```
A = "This Is A String With A /Linux/Path"
```

What On my way! Looking to extract is:

```
"/Linux/Path"
```

I'd also like it to be OS independent, so if:

```
A = "This is A String With A C:\Windows\Path"
```

I'd like to extract:

```
"C:\Windows\Path"
```

I'm guessing there is a way of doing it with regular expressions looking for `/` or `\` but I just wondered if there was a more pythonic way?

I'm happy to take the risk that `/` or `\` may exist in another part of the main string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split at [`os.sep`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/os.html#os.sep) and take the results that are longer than one:

```
import os

def get_paths(s, sep=os.sep):
    return [x for x in s.split() if len(x.split(sep)) > 1]
```

On Linux / OSX:

```
>>> A = "This Is A String With A /Linux/Path"
>>> get_paths(A)
['/Linux/Path']
```

For multiple paths:

```
>>> B = "This Is A String With A /Linux/Path and /Another/Linux/Path"
>>> get_paths(B)
['/Linux/Path', '/Another/Linux/Path']
```

Mocking Windows:

```
>>> W = r"This is A String With A C:\Windows\Path"
>>> get_paths(W, sep='\\')
['C:\\Windows\\Path']
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply - that should work a treat!